# Add Img in navbar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

---

Hello all!

I have a svg image which I want to put in a navbar from bootstrap. 
I have some issues with the size of the picture. I would like that its behavior is the same as button with class btn.

Here an image, here flags are inside buttons and I want flags are same height as buttons and don't inside button but inside `<a>`.

[image: Example]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13650140/2441442

Comment: Nop. I just found how to resolve the issue.Here an example who works : http://jsfiddle.net/c6f1ecrv/4/