# Using svg images as buttons - but not include them in the HTML directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a few button images, saved as svgs. I now want to use these images as buttons on my html site. However, I have no idea how to accomplish this.

The images are quite complex, so I do not want them to be inside the actual HTML file, but import them from a separate file (I just mean, I want them to be saved as .svg files separately).The second problem (of which I do not know whether it is a problem or not) is that the buttons are round.

I have thought of solving this by including the buttons as background images in css, or just as standard images which I think give an onclick method, but surely the last method is way too complicated, and making them background images also seems very counter-intuitive to me. I'm just writing this to show that I have thought about this, but do not know.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
<div class="sw-buttons">
                <button id="sw-button-1" />
                </button>

                <button id="sw-button-2" />
                </button>
                ...(more buttons here)
            </div>
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649872/can-i-make-an-svg-image-button), but here the svg is included straight in the HTML.

Comment: Why don't you just set them as background-image on the `<button>` elements?

Comment: Use an external SVG file - see this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-svg-image-sprites/)

Comment: is setting them as css background images fine? I would have thought it's bad practice.

Comment: [This article from CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-2) explains the various ways to include SVG files on a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You can include your external svg as the `src` of an `<img />` inside a `<button>...</button>` element:

```css
button, button img {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
}

button {
position: relative;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

button img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
<img src="/my-svg-button.svg" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store them on your server and access them using the code:

```
    #sw-button-1:
    background: url(put_the_link_to_your_image_here) no-repeat left top;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

    #sw-button-2:
    background: url(put_the_link_to_your_image_here) no-repeat left top;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
```

You can adjust the height and width of the buttons accordingly.